# How to set charset for wp_remote_post request?

Tags: encoding, http-api, wp-remote-post

I'm using `wp_remote_post()` on a project and it works great. But seems like the server on which I need to make the POST request is a Windows (ISS) server. So the third-party service that provides this specific endpoint requires that all POST requests has a **Windows-1252** character encoding, otherwise there will be issues with special characters (like á, é, û, etc).

I did some research and seems like the way to go is to set a `Content-Type` HTTP header which includes a charset (like `charset=Windows-1252`). Tried to add the charset along with the content type (like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=Windows-1252`), but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know how to proper set the charset for an HTTP POST request using `wp_remote_post()`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally the charset is assigned with `=`, so you could try `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=Windows-1252`

Comment: I noticed that according to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields) the `Content-Type` is a response field, not a request field. I thought it was also valid as a request field? There we see e.g. the `Accept-Charset` request field, but I'm don't think that's what you need. Have you tried encoding the POST data manually ?

Comment: @birgire you're totally right, and that's what I was using, the snippet here is incorrect but on my source code it is correct. Just fixed the typo on my question.

Comment: @birgire actually on the link you sent the `Content-Type` is also a request field. And to define the charset, it seems that this is the correct approach: https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index.en

Comment: aha I now see that Content-Type is also listed as a request field, as expected, I guess I scrolled down too fast ;-) But I'm not sure how the Windows server treats it, if it can encode it accordingly or you need to encode the POST data manually as well.

Comment: @birgire you're suggesting to maybe using `urlencode()` on the POST variables? I'll try that later and will update here the results.

Comment: @birgire thanks for the help, your tip about encoding the POST data, I found a workaraound! See my answer below.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear you found a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

After trying several times to set the proper charset, I wasn't successful. Then I searched for an workaround and found one that worked with my problem.

In addition to set the charset like I mentioned above, what I did is to convert all strings on my POST body with this php snippet:

```php
$message = @iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252//IGNORE",$message);
```

This converts all of your characters into compatible `Windows-1252` strings. For me, it worked, and all special characters are properly recognizable on the ISS server.